# what am i missing android.telephony.PhoneNumberUtils

Tags: android, sms

i have an android app that needs to listen for incoming sms messages. i then need to display the senders name associated with the sending telephone number.
my probelm is that the originating address has the country code prefix, where as my contacts does not.

how can i cope with this situation? i was hoping

```
android.telephony.PhoneNumberUtils
```

could help but none of its methods seems to be of any use in this case.

surely there must be some android utilities that can convert between numnbers with and without country code prefixes.

for example the smsManager always appears to give me originatingaddress with +44 prefix, whereas some of my personal contacts do not have this prefix attached. am i going to have to code a conversion prcess myself? or use a LIKE predicate when using contentResolver to get my telephone contact display name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using `PhoneNumberUtils.compare(number1, number2)` and it works just fine.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#compare(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#compare%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: incrediApp, thanks for your time on responding to my question... compare does give true for a number +44 prefixed however its not going to help me here (or i cannot see it!) as i want to use the originating address (that is +44 prefixed) to retrieve my contact display name that is stored against the NOT +44 prefixed number. the only way compare is goint to help me is if i browse all my contact telephone numbers doing a compare on each one in turn until i get true

Comment: I don't see any other way you can do that... There are a few options for a number to appear in. this method is supposed to return true when the numbers are identical for caller id purposes, meaning, you have to compare the number with the numbers you want to check (or the entire contacts list).
It seems odd that you've tried to compare 2 numbers that are with and without the +44 prefix and received false... Can you give an example?

Comment: i found this google library http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/ it can parse a country prefixed telephone number and separate out the country code from the actual telephone numnber. by parsing my +44 prefixed number i can find my saved contact. thanks for your time incrediApp